# Ajax to PHP Call

Tags: php, ajax, file, local

For some reason my ajax code is not working with another server that I transferred my client-side code to. When my client-side code was on a different server, it worked fine.

PHP code host: 
[Host](http://www.clubbedin.zymichost.com)

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'some url on that same server',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'uID': userID
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#clubcontent').empty();
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(json);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
                $('#clubcontent').append('<li><a href="#" data-club-id=\"' + json[i].id + '\" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>');
            $('#clubcontent').listview('refresh');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("not connecting");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You sir, are having problems with the Same Origin Policy!

Comment: In all my php files I have header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

Comment: Maybe use jsonp? `dataType: jsonp`